# Determine the ABI of the current build in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to programmatically determine the ABI (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, etc) of the current build in the build.gradle file?

I've tried creating a function like this:

```
def getABIFromCurrentBuild() {
    return android.os.Build.CPU_ABI;
}
```

but the android.os package isn't available from the Gradle plugin.

**Background:**

I have an app project in Android Studio which uses a JNI library.  The JNI library, in turn, links to a static C++ library that's built outside of Android Studio using Makefiles.  However, the static library is split into different versions (one for each ABI).

I want to avoid creating Makefiles for the JNI library and just use an ndk block in my app's build.gradle file within Android Studio.  Here's what my ndk block looks like:

```
ndk {
    moduleName "myJNILib"
    cFlags "-std=c++11"
    ldLibs "GLESv3 ${project.projectDir}/../../build/local/${getABIFromCurrentBuild()}/myStaticLib.a"
    stl "gnustl_shared"
}
```

As you can see, I've hacked my static library into the linker command-line when building the JNI library, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to link the right version of it in.

I've also tried separating all of the ABI types out into a productFlavors block like this:

```
productFlavors {
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
            moduleName "myJNILib"
            cFlags "-std=c++11"
            ldLibs "GLESv3 ${project.projectDir}/../../build/local/x86/myStaticLib.a"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86_64"
            moduleName "myJNILib"
            cFlags "-std=c++11"
            ldLibs "GLESv3 ${project.projectDir}/../../build/local/x86_64/myStaticLib.a"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

which gets everything linked correctly, but then the JNI shared library is only copied into some of the apks due to the fact that the apk naming scheme used by the Gradle plugin is much more complex than what I've captured in the productFlavors.

For example, one of the apks is named "app-arm64-x86_64-debug".  In which case there's no ABI filter that matches.

**Update**

For now, I've avoided the need for a separate static library by simply adding a symlink to my static library code in `<project>/app/src/main/jni/`.  That gets it compiled directly into the JNI library, which is essentially the same effect as linking to a static library anyway.  Plus it has the benefit that the library source code shows up in Android Studio, which makes it easier to access.

Comment: There really is no "current build". Stuff like the `productFlavors` closure are configuring an object model; they are not some sort of procedural script.

Comment: Yeah, I knew the `productFlavors` construct wasn't designed to be used for this purpose. I just showed it to give a better idea of what I'm doing (and what I've already tried).